# id delegate unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, unrecognized-selector

I have two classes

Class A.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

-(void)displayAllGroups:(NSArray *)groups;
```

Class A.m File

```
@synthesize delegate;

view didLoad {

    _array_groups = [Group getAllGroups:json];

    if ([_array_groups isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"type of NSArray");//   
        [delegate displayAllGroups:_array_groups];// error
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"not a type of NSArray");
     }
}
```

This is implementation of A class where I used id delegate for sending `group_array` to b class. B class is blow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GroupsViewController *groupView=[[GroupsViewController alloc]init];
    [groupView setDelegate:self];
}
-(void)displayAllGroups:(NSArray *)groups
{
    NSLog(@"all groups arrays are:%@",groups);
}
```

note: Error is `[delegate displayAllGroups:_array_groups];` `-[HomeViewController displayAllGroups:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbfcb644b20'`

Comment: Delegate defination ??

Comment: we can use id delegate without definition there is error of unrecognized selector

Comment: The message is clear - The object that is set as your delegate is an instance of `HomeViewController` and it doesn't implement the method `displayAllGroups:`. Also your code as shown doesn't make much sense - You allocate a `GroupsViewController` - but this is in a local variable so it will be released as soon as `viewDidLoad` exits.

Comment: you are right @Paulw11 i set same id delegate in tow classes for tow individual task in tow different classes so how i solve my problem, how can set it global

Comment: I don't see how setting it globally will help you - you do need to ensure that the object that is set as the delegate implements the required method.  Using the protocol definitions as @bunty suggests will give you warnings if an object doesn't implement required protocol methods.  You can also flag a method as `@optional` in your protocol definition but in this case you should use `respondsToSelector` before invoking the delegate method

Answer (score 1):

Creating protocol for B class as below

```
@protocol B_Delegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)displayAllGroups:(NSArray *)groups;
@end
```

And changing the delegate declaration as below

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <B_Delegate> delegate;
```

will remove the error.

Comment: This will help the compiler know what you are talking about and avoid the use of `id` but it won't magically implement a missing method which is what the exception says is the problem.